# Simple implementation of react native screen change

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am new at react native and i am trying to implement the navigation from one screene to the other and it is a bit hard because sources are old and do not work as possible solutions for current react native version, i know that this question is not the best question to make here but i rally need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

navigation you can do something like this.  lets have quick look at example:

RootStack.js

```
 import createAnimatedSwitchNavigator from 'react-navigation-animated-switch';
 import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';
 const RootStack = createAnimatedSwitchNavigator(
 {
    splash:SplashScreen,
    second:SecondScreen,
},
{
   initialRouteName: splash
}
)
export default RootStack;
```

APP.js

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import AuthStack from './AuthStack'
const RootStack = createStackNavigator({ RootStack});
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);
export default AppContainer;
```

your component should be like this.

```
...rest
const SplashScreen = (props) =>{
    return (
        <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{
                props.navigation.navigate("second")
        }}></TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}
export default withNavigation(SplashScreen)
```